# Data parsing issue

Tags: angular, typescript

My firebase API returned JSON looks like below

```
{    
 one:{  
     fullName: "1",
     id: "1",
     subDistrict: "1"
     zone: "1"  
    },  
two:{  
     fullName: "2",
     id: "2",
     subDistrict: "2"
     zone: "3"  
   },   
}
```

I have created data model likes below

```
interface users{
  user: data
}

interface data { 
  fullName:string,
  id:string,
  zone:string,
  subDistrict:string
}
```

I am receiving procedure form angular firebase

```
this.source=(<users>snap.val());
```

data is recieved properly,

```
console.log(this.source) //ok
```

But
I am not able to access it

```
console.log(this.source.user);//undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because your this.source doesn't contain `user` key.
If your format of your json is as you mentioned, you should do this:

```
console.log(this.source.one, this.source.two);
```

... instead of

```
console.log(this.source.user);
```